# Mongoose with field of type number shall allow undefined as an empty value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose

I'm using `mongoose` and I'm Having a some fields that I've defined with `{type : Number}`.

The problem is that I'm getting very often a validation error Like:

```
CastError: Cast to number failed for value "undefined" at path "xxxx"
```

I've looked into the [Mongoose relevant cod](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/4.13.7/lib/schema/number.js)e, seems like this is thier validation logic for number:

```
return typeof value === 'number' || value instanceof Number;
```

So, any falsy value like `undefined` or `null` will be rejected.

My question is there's an easy way to allow falsy values to be treated as empty.
My intention with doing a type for a field (If I don't set `{required : true }`) is only to reject other truthy values that are not Numbers, I would like to ignore any falsy value.

Comment: If required is set to false then undefined is already allowed. Are you trying to use the string "undefined" rather than the type?

Comment: I'm just not defining some property and this is what I got

Comment: Is required not `false` by default?

Comment: Yes, it is. I mean not setting `required: true`.

Comment: Yes it is. Re-read MikaS first comment. You must be passing in some value because it's trying to cast it.

Comment: No, I'm not passing anything.

Comment: the most that I can think of. I assign it to another variable that is not defined.

Comment: Probably your code can solve the mystery

Comment: Well,  I will look deeper. Thanks